# Sending information from Laravel back end to React front end without making request from front first

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, webhooks

I have a Laravel / React application which can receive webhooks from a third party service. When something is updated at that third party service it POST's to a certain endpoint in my Laravel application and I can then do stuff with whatever it posts. Typically this would be store that information or whatever within the back end / database but what I am trying to do is update the front end in real time if the third party service gets updated...is this even possible?

I know its annoying when people don't post code but I don't really have a lot at this point and am just wondering how this might be achieved at all.

Comment: You are looking for websockets and broadcasting https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting

Comment: I think this is indeed what I'm looking for! If you want some internet points then answer the question with this and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for websockets and broadcasting https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting